# $\ell^\infty$ and $\ell^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Show that $\ell^\infty$ and $\ell^1$ are normed linear spaces.

Solution:

Since $\ell^p$ is the collection of real sequences $a=(a_1,a_2, ... )$ for which $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|^p < \infty$ and in $\ell^\infty$, $\sup_{1 \leq k < \infty} |a_k|$. Does this merely require checking the properties of a norm (Triangle-Inequality, Positive Homogeneity, Non-negativity)?

Comment: excuse the mistake in the title.

Comment: you can always edit your answer, as soon as you discover mistakes, see the edit option below your question.

Comment: You may  also have to verify that they are linear spaces.

Comment: so, I need to show:

summation, multiplication, associativity, commutativity, etc. ?

Comment: Or, show that the space $F$ of all infinite sequences is a linear space (hopefully you have this result in hand), and that $\ell_1$ and $\ell_\infty$ are subspaces of $F$ (non-empty and closed under addition and scalar multiplication).

Comment: to be precis you need to verify that they are linear spaces, scalar multiplication and addition, and that the map to $\mathbb{R}$ is indeed a norm with the properties you just stated.

Comment: From my book (Royden "Real Analysis" 4th, p. 136):

"There is a natural family ${L^p (E)}_{1 \leq p \leq \infty}$ of subspaces of $F$... define ${L^p (E)}$ to be the collection of equivalence classes $[f]$ for which

$\int_E |f|^p < \infty$"

Later,

"we infer from this inequality, together with the linearity and monotonicity of integration, that if [f] and [g] belong to $L^p (E)$, so also does the linear combination... Therefore, $L^p (E)$ is a linear space.



Is this what you were refering to David?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall first that the set of all real sequences $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}^*}=\{a=(a_n)_{n\geq 1}\}\;|\;a_n\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a real vector space.

Now denote $\|a\|_\infty:=\sup_{n\geq 1}|a_n|$ and $\|a\|_p:=\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}|a_n|^p\right)^{1/p}$ for $p\geq 1$.
For every $a\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}^*}$, it is clear that both $\|a\|_\infty$ and $\|a\|_p$ are nonnegative or infinite.

Next define $\ell_\infty:=\{a\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}^*}\;|\;\|a\|_\infty<\infty\}$ and $\ell_p:=\{a\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}^*}\;|\;\|a\|_p<\infty\}$.

Then note that the null sequence $(0,0,0,\ldots)$ belongs to both $\ell_\infty$ and $\ell_p$, so that they are nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}^*}$.

Now, indeed, it only remains to prove that $\|a\|_\infty$ and $\|a\|_p$ satisfy the three axioms of a norm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics):

1)positive homogeneity

2)triangle inequality

3)separation.

It will follow from 1) and 2) that both $\ell_\infty$ and $\ell_p$ are stable under linear combinations, hence vector (linear) subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}^*}$.
This will show that they are normed vector (linear) spaces.

1) is easy for both $\ell_\infty$ and $\ell_p$.

2) is easy for $\ell_\infty$ and for $\ell_p$, it follows from the Minkowski inequality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality

3) is easy for both $\ell_\infty$ and $\ell_p$.

I hope this helps.